Не подключается static/style.css в Django

Из настроек:
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "main/static/"),
]

Из HTML: ({% load static %} - присутствует.)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">


Приложите к вопросу структуру каталога static/.

Приложил скриншот

где находится папка main?

main - приложение, находиться в папке bad_site

И над ним еще одна папка, разумеется, тоже с названием bad_site

Не забудьте о {% load static %} в верхней части страницы.

{% load static %} присутствует

settings.py
DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = []

my_app.urls.py
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path("", index, name='home'),
    ...
    ...
    re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    ]

index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="ru">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'my_app/css/style.css' %}">
</head>

проверь парвильность ссылки на *.css.
далее в терминале вводишь:
python manage.py collectstatic

данная команда собирает статические файлы из каждого вашего приложения (и любых других указанных вами мест) в одном месте, которое можно легко обслуживать в процессе производства.
запускаешь:
python manage.py runserver

не забудь обновить браузер, что бы стили подтянулись.
должно работать.
